# How to prove that Lebesgue outer measure is monotone?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, lebesgue-measure

It is very clear that if $A \subset B $ then $m^*(A)\leq m^*(B)$.

But how to prove it ?

Most of the books says that it is obvious. But what is the proof ?

Comment: Any cover of $B$ is a cover of $A$.

Comment: Just a comment on mathematical I don't know the word, integrity or something: If you don't see how to prove it you shouldn't be saying it's clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\mathcal E$ to be the set 
$$\left\{
\sum\limits_{n≥1} \text{length}(I_n) \mid I_n \text{ intervals }, \bigcup_{n≥1} I_n \supset A
\right\}$$

and
$$\mathcal F = \left\{
\sum\limits_{n≥1} \text{length}(I_n) \mid I_n \text{ intervals }, \bigcup_{n≥1} I_n \supset B
\right\}$$

You have (since $B \supset A$): $$\mathcal F \subset \mathcal E$$

then
$$
\inf(\mathcal E) = m^*(A) ≤
\inf(\mathcal F) = m^*(B)$$

because "the larger your set is, the smaller the infimum will be".

Comment: As a quick addition to, "the larger your set is, the smaller the infimum will be," recall, $m^{*}:\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ and $\mathbb{R}^{*}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\big\{-\infty,+\infty\big\}$ is defined as the $extended$ real numbers. Now, $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ is a totally-ordered set, hence $[0,+\infty]$ is also a totally-ordered set (although $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ isn't even a semi-group). Recall a result from basic Real Analysis: Suppose $S$ is an ordered set, $B\subset S$ is bounded, and $\varnothing\neq A\subset B$. If all infimums exist, then we have $\inf(B)\leq\inf(A)$.